How should I understand "mit" in this sentence?
From here:

Erstmals forderte mit Peter Welch ein Senator der Demokraten Biden öffentlich auf, aus dem Rennen um das Weiße Haus auszusteigen.

I have difficulty understanding the mit above.
Actually I'm not sure what the subject of the sentece is: is it Peter Welch ein Senator der Demokraten (as name + position put appositively)?
The best guess I can make based on grammatical considerations is that it is mit as adverb, but somehow it does not look like the mit above "drückt das Dabeisein, Verbundensein, die Zugehörigkeit zu etw. aus". Or should I think it means simply auch or neben anderem?

Google translate has more trouble with "Welch" :-)

„For the first time, a Democrat senator, Peter Welch, publicly called on Biden to drop out of the race for the White House.„ DeepL is pretty good to help you understand the sentence.

@Lichtbringer Yes, I understand what the sentence means, even though I had only a year of German in college. I was amused that google translate didn't not understand that "Welch" was a proper name and not the German word, and returned gibberish.


Actually I'm not sure what the subject of the sentece is: is it Peter Welch ein Senator der Demokraten (as name+position put appositively)?

No. The "Peter Welch" is connected to the "mit". For example, "Mit Peter Welch forderte erstmals ein Senator der Demokraten..." would be a valid reshuffling.
Grammatically, "mit" is just a preposition. It's the meaning that is unusual.
The subject is "ein Senator der Demokraten", which is a general category. The "mit" phrase denotes the specific individual of that category who did the things. By putting it that way, the author puts a lot of emphasis on the general category. So, it is important that a democratic senator said something, and the fact that it was Peter Welch is additional information.
Also note that the "erstmals" relates to "Senator", not to "Peter Welch". It's the first time a democratic senator said that, not (only) the first time Peter Welch said that.
I think English sometimes uses "in" in a similar way, but I'm not sure it would sound good in a translation of this sentence. Edit: Jan Olieslagers' suggestion of "in the person of" sounds good to me.

From my experience, an English version of the sentence could actually use "with": "With Peter Welch, the first Democratic senator called for...". It would need some reconstruction, for example going from "for the first time" to "the first senator", but the construction the question was about would be quite similar.

The subject of the sentence is "ein Senator der Demokraten".
The "mit" construction unfortunately doesn't have a very good equivalent in English and dictionaries are not very helpful either, those that I checked do not seem to list this usage as a separate meaning.
The meaning is "for the first time, a senator of the Democrats, specifically Peter Welch, publicly called for Biden to drop out of the race for the White House".
You can use "mit" in this way: "mit (concrete object or person) tut erstmals/letztmals/zum dritten Mal/... (general class of objects or people) etwas". Wiktionary has an example under mit: "Mit Seehofer besucht erstmals ein bayerischer Ministerpräsident das Nachbarland Tschechien." This likewise translates to "For the first time, a Bavarian minister-president, specifically Seehofer, is visiting the neighboring country of Czechia."

DWDS lists this under definition III: "bezeichnet die Gleichzeitigkeit eines Vorganges, Zustandes mit einem bestimmten Zeitpunkt oder einem anderen Geschehen" -- "refers to the simultaneity of a process, state with a certain point in time or another event", and it gives other examples. I'm not convinced that this really clears things up for an English speaker, but then that's not the target audience for DWDS.

PS. For what it's worth, I'd render it as "for the first time, a Democratic senator, namely Peter Welch, publicly called for ..." Americans don't say "senator of the Democrats" (or Republicans for that matter). "Namely" and "specifically" are more or less interchangeable, but "namely" seems more natural here.

Read the "mit" as "in the person of".

Let's analyze this sentence:

Erstmals forderte mit Peter Welch ein Senator der Demokraten Biden öffentlich auf

This is the Hauptsatz (the main clause). It is incomplete because it does not contain the action to which the object of the sentence was called.

aus dem Rennen um das Weiße Haus auszusteigen.

This is a "Finalsatz" (a purpose clause).  It contains the action to which the object was called. It contains many parts, but in the end it is an "Infinitivsatz" (an infinitive clause) with some additional things, but that was not the subject of the question.
Let's dive deeper into the main clause:
The pivot of every sentence is its verb. So, what is the verb? The verb is a form of "auffordern" which is a separable verb, here split into its two parts and inflected according to its grammatical environment: "forderte ... auf" (to call someone to do something).
This verb needs a subject as its most important complement. In the case of "auffordern", this subject names the person making the request, and this is: "ein Senator der Demokraten". This subject is a noun phrase in nominative case that has a core noun (Senator) in nominatiove case singular, left of it a determiner that is realized as an indefinite article (ein) matching with its core noun in case and number (nominative singular) and right of it a possessive attribute, realized as another (inner) noun phrase in genitive case, again with a core noun (Demokraten; plural of Demokrat) in genitive case and a definite article in genitive case plural (der).
The second complement that the verb "auffordern" needs is an object in accusative case that contains the person that is called to do something. This accusative object is a noun phrase with only one word, that is "Biden" in accusative case singular.
The next complement that "auffordern" needs is the action, to which the subject calls the object, and this is the purpose clause that was mentioned earlier.
These three ingredients is all you need to build a sentence with the verb "auffordern":

Das Subjekt fordert das Objekt auf, etwas zu tun.
Der Lehrer fordert den Schüler auf, zur Tafel zu kommen.
Ein Senator der Demokraten forderte Biden auf, aus dem Rennen um das Weiße Haus auszusteigen.

(The form "fordert ... auf" is Präsens, German's present tense, but "forderte ... auf" is Präteritum, one of German's three past tenses)
You sentence contains two additional parts of speech that are not mandatory for sentences with the verb "auffordern":

Erstmals
This is an adverb that modifies the meaning of the verb. As such, it is so closely tied to the verb that it is considered part of the predicate. (The term predicate is defined differently in German and English. In English, the predicate is everything but the subject. In German, however, the predicate is usually only the verb. Only parts that directly modify the meaning of the verb are part of the predicate in a German sentence).

mit Peter Welch
This is a prepositional phrase that starts with the preposition "mit". This preposition forces the rest of the prepositional phrase (the name "Peter Welch") to be in dative case.
Prepositional phrases can be used for multiple purposes in German sentences. Here it is used as an "adverbiale Bestimmung" (adverbial phrase), so, although being made of three words, it works like an adverb, i.e. with a similar mechanism as "erstmals" works.
Prepositional phrases that start with "mit" introduce a companion to the sentence, i.e. someone who was present when the action happened. But on the syntactic layer this optional companion has no connection to other parts of speech. It might be someone who was there watching the action passively, it could be someone who is related to the requester, i.e. to the subject, but it might also be someone who is connected with the receiver of the call, i.e. to the object.
To understand the real meaning, you need to understand the semantic layer. What is the meaning of "mit Peter Welch"? Which role is Peter Welch playing? These are the possibilities:

passive watcher
This is not very convincing. Why would someone name a person who neither makes the call nor is addressed by the call? This possibility cannot be 100% excluded, but it is still very unlikely.
connected to the object
This means that Peter Welch is playing a role that is very similar to that of the object Biden, i.e. he is called to stop running for president. But Welch is not running for president, so this makes no sense.
connected to the subject
This means that Peter Welch is playing a role that is very similar to that of the subject (ein Senator der Demokraten = a senator of the democrats), and hey, Peter Welch is indeed a Democratic senator. This is a perfect match and this is the real meaning.



So, this sentence is just another way to say this:

Peter Welch war der erste Senator der Demokraten, der Biden öffentlich aufforderte, aus dem Rennen um das Weiße Haus auszusteigen.
Peter Welch was the first Democratic senator to publicly call on Biden to drop out of the race for the White House.

Original Sentence:

Erstmals forderte mit Peter Welch ein Senator der Demokraten Biden öffentlich auf, aus dem Rennen um das Weiße Haus auszusteigen.
With Peter Welch, for the first time a Democrat senator publicly called on Biden to drop out of the race for the White House.


A very detailed analysis, but it would be unusual to use "with" that way in English, and I think that's why the sentence is confusing for English speakers. Since the sentence is talking about an event, I would expect "with" to be followed by another event: "With the fall of the Soviet Union, the Cold War ended." Peter Welsh is not an event, but the sentence might be rephrased to make "with" possible: "With the Peter Welsh announcement, ... ." It would be better though to completely rephrase and use "specifically" or "namely" as in wonderbear's answer.

The sentence has two possible interpretations.
Interpretation 1:
"mit" as a short form of "mitunter". Here the author wants to express that Peter Welch is also among those calling for it.
Interpretation 2:
The author wants to express that even a Democratic senator is among those calling for it.
Without context it is not possible to distinguish between those two interpretations.
